# Add torrent name to PowerShell script that runs after it finishes downloading

Tags: powershell, bittorrent

I have a script to send a Pushover notification when a torrent finishes downloading through BitTorrent.
The script is:

```
$parameters = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
$parameters.Add("token", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzbzx")
$parameters.Add("user", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxWJcV")
$parameters.Add("message", "Your torrent has finished dowloading.")

$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.UploadValues("https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json", $parameters)
```

I want to add the name of the torrent.
On BitTorrent I have this running when a torrent finishes:

```
powershell.exe -noexit c:\Scripts\transfinish.ps
```

How can I do this.

Comment: What program are you running to download your torrents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro %N denotes the  title of the torrent. Run the commandline as:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File c:\Scripts\transfinish.ps "%N"
```

You can then access the arguments passed to the script using the $args variable.

For example:

```
$TorrentName = $args[0]
```

Comment: No. It gives some sort of error and then kills the command line.

Comment: Line 5 should be: $parameters.Add("message", "Your torrent $($arg[0]) has finished dowloading.")

Comment: My mistake, its $args[0] not $arg[0], I have updated the answer